# type script Argument of type '{ type: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPropertyBag'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui

- I tried integrate your code in my codebase which is typescript...
- I am getting an error like this 
  [ts] Argument of type '{ type: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPropertyBag'. Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'. (property) type: string[] a
  t this line ----------------> var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n"; let data = new Blob([csv], {type: mimeType});
- prviding code below.
- sample fiddle which is in normal js not in typescript.
- can you tell me how to fix it

http://jsfiddle.net/jcqtawad/

```or-tag-here
let types = ["text/plain", "application/pdf"];

let downloads = health.map(function(version) {
                  let ext = version.mobileVersion.replace(/.*(?=\.\w+)/, "");
                  let mimeType = types.filter(function(type) {
                                   return type.indexOf(ext) > -1
                                 });
                  let data = new Blob([/*  Blob data */], {
                               type: mimeType
                             });
                  return $("<a>", {
                           "class": "sportsDataPlayer",
                           download: ev.FileName + ext,
                           type: mimeType,
                           href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
                           html: ev.FileName
                         });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 Blob constructor accepts the value of MIMEtype as a string only and not as `string[]` as per the Blob constructor below

`new Blob(blobParts[, options])`

For example this below code works as the the value of `type` property is a `string`:

`let data = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain"});`

But in your code you are assigning a `string[]`  to the `type` property as per the code below where `mimeType` is still an array after using `filter`.

```
 let mimeType = types.filter(function(type) {
                                   return type.indexOf(ext) > -1
                                 });
```

hence you have to use it like below as MimeType should only contain a single value after filter by extension.

```
let data = new Blob([/*  Blob data */], {
                               type: mimeType[0]
                             });
```

Check out below links for more reference on Blob

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

https://dzone.com/articles/html5-blob-objects-made-easier